# How to show that the given integral equals a finite value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$$I=\int \limits_0^e x^{-x} dx$$

I am VERY confused on how to go about solving this integral. Please help.

Comment: The sophomore's dream can help but not sure whether same method can be used for any upper bound .

Comment: $x^{-x}$ is a continuous and bounded function on $(0,e)$, you do not need to "solve" anything.

Comment: $\approx \pi-{\rm arccot} \left(1/3\,{3}^{4/9} \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right) 
 \right) ^{7/5} \left( \zeta \left( 3 \right)  \right) ^{4/3}\right)
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to write the integrand $x^{-x}$ in the form $e^{-xlog(x)}$. This makes it easy to see that the integrand is positive for all $x$, and attains its maximum value when $x= 1/e$. The corresponding maximum value for the integrand of $e^{1/e}$. Since we are integrating over a finite interval (of width $e$), we can conclude that the integral is indeed finite:

$$0 < I < e * e^{1/e}$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the function $x^{-x}$ is continuous in the interval (0, e), so it is not necessary to prove or solve anything because
  in any point of this interval the function explodes to infinite or minus infinite. Finding a closed form is something different and I do not believe that this integral has one in which there are no infinite series.
Also remember that $0^ 0$ even if it is an "indeterminate" result, in its limit the function tends to 1.

$\lim_{n\to0^{+}} n^n=1$ and in the same way $\lim_{n\to0^{+}} n^{-n}=1$